# which Nosql Database is suited for a table with static schema and too much number of rows

Tags: database, nosql

There is a table with 5 columns and no more. The size of each row is less then 200 bytes but the number of the table rows may be increased to several tens of billions during the time.

The application will be storing data at a rate of 100 per second or more. Once these data are stored, they will never be updated but they will be removed after 1 year. They will not be read many times though, but may be queried by selecting within a time range, e.g. selecting rows for a given hour in a given day.

Questions

1. Which type of Nosql database is suited for this?
2. Which of these databases would be best suited? (Doesn't have to be listed)

Comment: Why must it be Nosql?  Just curious...

Comment: @TonyAndrews we are using Oracle database. our master table in database has 4 billions rows. A simple query on the table takes 15 minutes to complete and some times does not complete. So i think the better choose is to migrate Nosql databases

Comment: Really? Rather than tune the database (and query) you have?

Comment: I will sugest same as tony andrews, migrating to noSql with such a huge database will be no good. Tuning will be good try to reach beyond 4th normal form to break your master table into several tables, boost indexes and make query as optimized as possible. Nosql are good for files data especially, and for non relational db, even airways also use mongodb(no sql) but 4 billion rows is something behemoth, if nosql is must move to MongoDB, as its sharding ability will help optimize data itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your Oracle license includes the partitioning option, partition by month or year, and if most/all of your queries include the date column you partitioned on, that will help dramatically.  It also makes dropping a year's worth of data take a few seconds.

As others noted in the comments, depends on how much data is being returned by a query.  If a query is returning millions of rows, then yes, it may take 15 minutes.  Oracle can handle queries against billion row tables in a few seconds if the criteria is restricting enough and appropriate indexes are present, and statistics gathered appropriately.

So how many rows are returned by your 15 minute query?

Comment: in worst case, 100 rows are returned

Comment: So if you are inserting 100 rows a second, then partition by hour or day on  the time column that you will be querying in the where clause, and I guarantee your query will take milliseconds to run.  And with Oracle 12, you can include partition by interval, which means Oracle will automatically create partitions for each hour/day/month/year.